# JavaScript ES6 Filter Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hi I have an array and I want to filter it as I show below. I checked .reduce() , .filter(), .map() functions and couldn't find proper solution. Can you halp me with that? Thanks.

My array:

```js
var pilots = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Wedge Antilles",
    faction: "Rebels",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Ciena Ree",
    faction: "Empire",
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    name: "Iden Versio",
    faction: "Empire",
  },
  {
    id: 66,
    name: "Thane Kyrell",
    faction: "Rebels",
  }
];
```

And I want to filter it like:

```js
var pilots = [
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 8
  },
  {
    id: 40
  },
  {
    id: 66
  }
];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: `pilots.map({id} => ({id}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this way, it will work for you

```js
let pilots = [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Wedge Antilles",
      faction: "Rebels",
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Ciena Ree",
      faction: "Empire",
    },
    {
      id: 40,
      name: "Iden Versio",
      faction: "Empire",
    },
    {
      id: 66,
      name: "Thane Kyrell",
      faction: "Rebels",
    }
  ];


let Items = pilots.map(({ name, faction, ...rest }) => ({ ...rest }));

console.log(Items)
```

**OR**

```
 let result = pilots.map({id} => ({id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` the array and return only the *id*

```js
const mapped = pilots.map(({id}) => ({id}));

console.log (mapped)
```

```html
<script>
var pilots = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Wedge Antilles",
    faction: "Rebels",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Ciena Ree",
    faction: "Empire",
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    name: "Iden Versio",
    faction: "Empire",
  },
  {
    id: 66,
    name: "Thane Kyrell",
    faction: "Rebels",
  }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pilots = [
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Wedge Antilles",
    faction: "Rebels",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "Ciena Ree",
    faction: "Empire",
  },
  {
    id: 40,
    name: "Iden Versio",
    faction: "Empire",
  },
  {
    id: 66,
    name: "Thane Kyrell",
    faction: "Rebels",
  }
];

const idOnly = pilots.map(el => ({id :el.id}))

console.log(idOnly)
```